# AngularJS losing two way binding after JS form plugin rendering

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm hoping someone with a better understanding of AngularJS might be able to shed some light on whats going on here.

I have a webpage with a long form. After the JS form plugin is initialized, everything in the form no longer has two way data binding. JS plugin for reference can be found [here](http://www.jquery-steps.com/)

If I remove the id link to the JS plugin, thus not applying or rendering the steps plugin, all two way data binding works as expected.

I could post a lot of code here but I'm not sure that would help. I have no problem posting code at any request.

Any ideas on why the two way data binding is losing effect after rerendering a form tag and its contents?

Comment: Create a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/) with a small example and I'll take a look. I suspect you're setting strict values somewhere.

Comment: jQuery happens outside the context of AngularJS, so when you add the plugin to the form, it's like telling jQuery to take over.  If you can't build or find a suitable Angular directive, you can try using the jQuery Passthrough utility from UI Utils: http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-utils/

Comment: Working on the plunker, the button to add jquery-steps to the plunk is getting a 404 not found, any ideas for a workaround? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Post something even if it's broken. We have no idea how you are integrating plugin. If done in a directive it should work fine although you really should be able to use angular to achieve the same thing without the plugin

Answer (score 0):

I was actually able to get AngularJS to work correctly with this plugin by including the plugin at the bottom of the page instead of the top. So I think the key here was to let AngularJS load up first, then the page, then the jQuery Steps plugin (at the boom of the page that uses it).

Thanks all for your comments!

Answer (score 0):

Jquery library should include before angular library otherwise your site will try to use jquery instead of angular own lite jquery which will definitely break the binding.

Comment: Right now the first two includes in my project are angular.min.js and then jquery.min.js. And they are included in that order. All the data binding between angularjs, my external javascript functions, and data within the jquert steps plugin form are working correctly. This seems contradictory?

Comment: Put  jquery.min.js then angular.min.js

Comment: Ok, I flipped them around with no adverse effects, I'll keep them that way. Thanks for the advice!